# Gauss transforms to factor $A = LU$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

> Consider a symmetric matrix $A$, i.e., $A = A^{T}$. Consider the use of Gauss transforms to factor $A = LU$ where $L$ is unit lower triangular and $U$ is upper triangular. You may assume that the factorization does not fail. Show that $A = LDL^T$ where $L$ is unit lower triangular and $D$ is a matrix with nonzeros on the main diagonal.

Attempted solution - Assume that the Gaussian elimination does not fail so we have $$M^{-1}_{n-1}\ldots M_1^{-1}A = U$$
We know that $L = M_1^{-1},\ldots, M_{n-1}^{-1}$ and we wish to show that $A = LDL^T$. It seems that $D$ has to be redistricted in a way to show that $A = LDL^T$ Take for example $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1\\
1 & -2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
clearly $A = A^T$ so $A$ is symmetric. Then the $LU$ factorization of $A$ yields $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1\\
1 & -2\\
\end{pmatrix} = LU = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
1/4 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1\\
0 & -9/4\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
So applying the Gauss transformation $$M_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-1/4 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1\\
1 & -2\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1\\
0 & -9/4\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
i.e. $M_1 A = U$

How do I apply the same methodology to show that $A = LDL^T$?

Not really sure how to proceed with this problem any recommendations is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the details of the construction, merely the fact that it exists.

Let us write 
$$A = LU = LD\tilde{U},$$
where $L$ is unit lower-triangular as assumed, and where $\tilde{U}$ is unit upper-triangular. All we've done here is extract the diagonal of $U$ as as $D$. Since $A$ is symmetric, we have
$$A=LD\tilde{U}=\tilde{U}^\mathrm{T}DL^\mathrm{T} = A^\mathrm{T}.$$
Note that $\tilde{U}^\mathrm{T}$ is lower unit triangular, and $L^\mathrm{T}$ is upper unit triangular. A fact that we need now is that the inverse of a unit lower/upper triangular matrix is again unit lower/upper triangular (you should prove this).

Multiplying the above equation by $L^{-1}$ on the left and $(L^\mathrm{T})^{-1}$ on the right, we get
$$D\tilde{U}(L^\mathrm{T})^{-1} = L^{-1}\tilde{U}^\mathrm{T}D.$$
The left-hand side of the above equation is upper triangular, and the right-hand side is lower triangular, so for them to be equal, both have to be diagonal. Since all of the triangular matrices above are unit triangular, it follows that the diagonal matrix has to be $D$ itself. Therefore we conclude that
$$D = D\tilde{U}(L^\mathrm{T})^{-1},$$
from which follows
$$A=LD\tilde{U} = LDL^\mathrm{T},$$
as required. Finally, nothing precludes $0$s in the diagonal matrix $D$. There will necessarily be $0$s if $A$ were non-invertible.

Comment: I see so why does the problem ask to consider applying the Gauss transform to factor $A = LU$ it seems by your solution you just show that $A = LDL^T$ exists provided that $A$ is symmetric?

Comment: It's contingent on the existence of the $LU$ factorization. I had to assume both that $A=LU$ and that $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Ok, but in your solution you do not use Gauss transformation? Is Gauss transformation needed to answer the question?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a Gauss transform. If you mean Gauss-Jordan elimination, then that's just a way to find the factorization $A=LU$. It's not always guaranteed to exist, but Gaussian elimination will let you find it if it does.

Comment: If you see the example the Gauss transformation matrix is $M_1$

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't matter what the steps of the gaussian elimination are, the only fact that you need is that you can write $A=LU$. Gaussian elimination is just one of the ways of finding such a factorization. It really has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Ok, so at the step when you multiply the $L^{-1}$ and the $(L^{-1})^{T}$ i.e. $$L^{-1}A = L^{-1}LD\tilde{U} = (L^{-1})^{T}A^T = (L^{-1})^T\tilde{U}^T DL^T$$ I don't see how that equals what you have after that if I am making sense

Comment: Can you just help me with that part or just expand your answer on that aspect so I understand how to do it myself using your approach then I will accept your answer :)

Comment: I am multiplying by $L^{-1}$ on the left, and $(L^\mathrm{T})^{-1}$ on the right. So I am evaluating $L^{-1}A(L^\mathrm{T})^{-1} = L^{-1}A^\mathrm{T}(L^\mathrm{T})^{-1}$.

Comment: Not understanding you still

Comment: If you could provide more steps as you were explaining this to a small child then I am sure I can undestand

Comment: So, we have $A = LD\tilde{U} = \tilde{U}^\mathrm{T}DL^\mathrm{T} = A^\mathrm{T}$. Now, multiply on the left by $L^{-1}$, and we get $L^{-1}A = D\tilde{U} = L^{-1}\tilde{U}^\mathrm{T}DL^\mathrm{T} = L^{-1}A^\mathrm{T}$. Next, multiply on the right by $(L^\mathrm{T})^{-1}$, and we get $L^{-1}A(L^\mathrm{T})^{-1} = D\tilde{U}(L^\mathrm{T})^{-1} = L^{-1}\tilde{U}^\mathrm{T}D = L^{-1}A^\mathrm{T}(L^\mathrm{T})^{-1}$. Is that clearer?

Comment: Yes thank you!!

Comment: Sorry last question I now have $$D\tilde{U}(L^T)^{-1} = L^{-1}\tilde{U}^T D$$ how do I get $D$ by itself

Comment: Also assuming $D$ is what you say it is then $$A = LD\tilde{U} = L(D\tilde{U}(L^T)^{-1})\tilde{U} = \ldots = LDL^T$$ I don't see that either if you could expand on that as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40133/discussion-between-euyu-and-wolfy).